Remove missing reference in Excel VBA
I am trying to remove a reference that is to a library that some people in the company have and other does not. You can remove it manually but it is locked behind a password so I'm trying to disable it using code.
I have tried everything and every solution I try always end up with the same error ... the reference is not needed for the people that don't have the ".tlb" file, but it stops them from using other macros
The error is:

Sub RemoveBrokenReferences()
Dim i As Integer
Dim iCount As Integer
Dim theRef As Object


iCount = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.count
For i = iCount To 1 Step -1
Set theRef = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References(i)
    If theRef.IsBroken Then
        ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Remove theRef
    End If
Next
End Sub

I have tried everything.
EDIT2:
Error other people see when the open the file

What is the error that you get and when others are trying to use "other macros" in what way are they prevented from doing so?

Is this a Reference Library that you can Late-Bind only if it is needed, rather than Early-Binding it and trying to unbind it when it isn't needed?

@CHill60 i added a image of the error people see when the open the file

@Chronocidal I don't know VBA/programing enough to understand your phrasing I'm afraid

Extrapolating on the comment from @chronocidal:
This is an example of "early binding" which will require a Reference to the Microsoft Word nn Object Library
Set p_wordApp = New Word.Application

However, this is an example of "late binding" which does NOT require the reference
Set p_wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

The comment is suggesting that this is wrapped with an if statement e.g.
If required Then
    Set p_wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If

It means you don't have to try to remove the reference in code - you deploy without the reference in the first place.
As an aside, using late binding in deployed projects has the advantage that you will always end up trying to use the version of the object that is installed on the users machine, rather than the version that was on the machine where the project was built. So built-in auto updates if you like, but also overcomes disparities in builds across user groups.
Using early binding during development gives you intellisense which can speed up the development process.
Many of us do development with early binding, then remove the reference and switch to late binding before deploying. Always use Option Explicit and Debug, Compile to check your project first in case you leave in any constants named in the reference (for example, in my case I left in wdCollapseEnd)
